# Iterating through a string of long characters R

Tags: r, string, loops, character

So I have this 1 string of character which actually contain a lot of words in R:

```
texts <- c("cнесмотря выборами председателя хдс заключил союз министром здравоохранения шпаном  женатым геем позиционирующим защитника прав обычаев мигрантов панченко письменном объяснении подтвердила выложила фотографии целующихся юношей девушек считает гейпропагандой поцелуй губы входит традицию исконно русского приветствия включая поцелуи лицами пола")
```

What I wanted to do is to iterate through each of the words, so I used this code:

```
for(text in texts){
  print(text)
}
```

But it does not seem to iterate through each words, it just iterate the whole string of the characters.

Any solution to make R iterate through the words? Thanks in advance!

I tried to iterate through the one-length string which contain lots of characters using for loop, but it does not seem to retrieve the words, it just retrieve the whole sentence.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/29222063/9462095 one of the answers of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222019/converting-a-vector-of-sentences-to-vector-of-words-using-apply-functions, which takes one string, a dataframe or a list of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
texts <- c("cнесмотря выборами председателя хдс заключил союз министром здравоохранения шпаном  женатым геем позиционирующим защитника прав обычаев мигрантов панченко письменном объяснении подтвердила выложила фотографии целующихся юношей девушек считает гейпропагандой поцелуй губы входит традицию исконно русского приветствия включая поцелуи лицами пола")

split_texts <- strsplit(x=texts,
                        split=" ")

  for(text in split_texts){
    print(text)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `scan`.

```
> scan(text=texts, what=character(), quiet=TRUE) 
 [1] "cнесмотря"       "выборами"        "председателя"    "хдс"            
 [5] "заключил"        "союз"            "министром"       "здравоохранения"
 [9] "шпаном"          "женатым"         "геем"            "позиционирующим"
[13] "защитника"       "прав"            "обычаев"         "мигрантов"      
[17] "панченко"        "письменном"      "объяснении"      "подтвердила"    
[21] "выложила"        "фотографии"      "целующихся"      "юношей"         
[25] "девушек"         "считает"         "гейпропагандой"  "поцелуй"        
[29] "губы"            "входит"          "традицию"        "исконно"        
[33] "русского"        "приветствия"     "включая"         "поцелуи"        
[37] "лицами"          "пола"
```